# send value from combobox to textarea

Tags: javascript, html

I have a textarea

```
<textarea id="tarea" class="textarea" cols="15" rows="10" disabled></textarea>
```

and I want to send the values from my comboboxes to the textarea

```
<div class="form-group col-xl-7">

    <label>Livro</label>
    <div id="combo">

        <select id="comboLivros">
            <option class="option"></option>
        </select>

    </div>

    <br>

    <label>Proprietário a que se refere</label>
    <input type="text" id='prop_desc' disabled/>

    <br>

    <label>Pontuação</label>
    <select  id="seleciona">

    </select>
</div>
```

Those are my combobox that are filled with an array

I want when I select the comboboxes with the values i choose when I click on a button I want the textarea to be filled
this is how I fill one of my combobox

```
var select = document.getElementById("seleciona");
var options = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var opt = options[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    select.appendChild(el);
}
```

this is how I fill one of my combobox

Answer (score 1):

You can use event change of select to set value of textarea:

```js
var select = document.getElementById("seleciona");
var options = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var opt = options[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    select.appendChild(el);
}
var textarea = document.getElementById("tarea");
select.onchange = function(){
    textarea.value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
    
}
```

```html
<textarea id="tarea" class="textarea" cols="15" rows="10" disabled></textarea>
<div class="form-group col-xl-7">

    <label>Livro</label>
    <div id="combo">

        <select id="comboLivros">
            <option class="option"></option>
        </select>

    </div>

    <br>

    <label>Proprietário a que se refere</label>
    <input type="text" id='prop_desc' disabled/>

    <br>

    <label>Pontuação</label>
    <select  id="seleciona">

    </select>
</div>
```

I hope it help you.

Comment: what is supose to put in the args  function(...args){

Comment: You don't need it.